# Starting to Run in Threadmill

Tags: running, cardio, stretching, jogging, treadmill

I decided to start with running since there's a treadmill in our house.
I have very low stamina, that's why I have decided to start running.

I have no exercise since I was born.
I am 5 feet and 9 inches (~ 176 cm) and around 2 months ago, I was 64kg. I don't know how much I weigh now but probably a bit heavier since I just almost sit for these past 2 months.

The treadmill only has a max speed of 12 kilometers per hour.

Any tips before (like stretching), during and after running? Like for example, stretch a bit before running, then walk for 2-3 mins on 3kmph, then switch to 6kmph for 3-5 mins and lastly, go for 9kmph as long as I can. After that, go again to 6kmph for 3-5 mins and 3kmph for 2-3 mins.

Comment: Stretch your hamstrings before and after you run.

Comment: What is your goal? Just to increase fitness and stamina? Or are you training for a specific purpose?

Answer (score 4):

From my personal experience, I can say that stretching is required neither before nor after the treadmill running workouts, unless you are planning to sprint at high speeds there, which I do not recommend at all. 5 mins of walking before and after worked fine for me.

What you will need if you want to run comfortably in a treadmill is a fan to blow air onto your front side and a TV or other device to get your head busy during the workout. Treadmill running is boring as hell.

I began running with a treadmill. My first workouts were at 8-9 km/h at about 1 km length. Then I slowly progressed, increasing the length and then gradually switching to 10-11 km/h speed. After I could run 2-3 kms on a treadmill, I switched to outdoor running, which is so much more fun!

Answer (score 1):

Running is not just physical endurance, but includes building up and increasing flexibility of the muscles, proper form, timing, and developing mental endurance.

What you may need to do is start from the bottom and build yourself up. Build up leg, calves, and feet/ankle strength. Expand into your back and sides because when running your body will also move slightly.

When you start building yourself up, running is probably the last thing to come.

1) just start walking on the treadmill. Comfortable pace. See how long you can go. 5 minutes? 10? Try turning the walk to a brisk walk like you're trying to not look like you're in a hurry, but you want to get somewhere faster.

If you're early on and barely even breaking a sweat then you can likely move to the next level.

2) Jog. Just jog. If you compare walking to jogging your knees go higher.

That should be enough over time to get some basic conditioning into you for running. There are exercises to compliment the build up, including and not limited to: jumping jacks, squats, and heel raises. Squats and heel raises you can hold on to a railing or chair to reduce the weight. Eventually you can move to do them without assistance.

When running you need to control your timing (aka pace). Don't worry about going 12km/hr. Cars burn more fuel the faster you try to go, the same with your body. Everything is a slow build up to increasing your speed, but to do that you need to start slow.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard C25k is a pretty popular program for people who are wanting to begin running. I plan on starting it soon.

Answer (score -2):

HIIT is the most effective way.

Try running 1 minute with the speed of about 10km/h and then go down to 5km/h for 1 minute.